# How do I make a public download page for my CartoDB table?

Tags: carto

I have some CartoDB data that I'd like to make available to people as shapefile, geojson and csv.

I just came across http://opensandiego.cartodb.com/tables/5037/public/map which has a great map preview, with downloads in different format and a cool table view. I have a number of public CartoDB tables, but I can't find how to share my data in that nice page. Is there a button to create the url? Or some way I can figure out what that URL should be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When looking at a public map or table in CartoDB, if you copy the URL and share it with someone else, they will be redirected to this /public/map version. Here they can view but not edit. They can also download like you say.

If you want to add download links to your own websites, it is also possible to create direct links in your HTML to any of the file formats we offer. For example, a CSV download link would look like this,

```
<a href=
    "http://username.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20table_name&format=CSV">
    Download CSV
</a>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The url should be:

http://< username >.cartodb.com/tables/< table_name or table_id >/public

Remember to make it public, if not that public table will not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Details for how to do this are on the CartoDB support page "Making Calls to the SQL API":
https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api/making-calls/